# Payment Method Title don't show

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

I create a custom payment method, all is working except the title in the checkout.

In the admin, I can see it, all looks good, I can change all and they persist in the database.

I can see the radio button in the checkout (without the title)

I can get in the observer the method by code.

The only part I can't get is the Title, and I don't know if exist some way to get it by their code.

Any idea?

UPDATE

Ok, I tried something and work, but I want to know if my deduction is correct:

```
protected $_code = 'payment_custom'; //doesn't work with the underscore
protected $_code = 'paymentcustom'; // work
```

I'm still testing if the code name must be the same as the module_name

makes sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

For the title in your system config your payment method title should be under `<title> </title>` because generally, Magento get the title of Payment method from using [`getTitle()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Abstract.php#L602)([`app\design\frontend\YOUR_PACKAGE\YOUR_THEME\template\checkout\onepage\payment.phtml`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml#L49)) method and in this method you can see that it is written as in `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract` (Not sure If your payment method class is overridden )

```
 public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->getConfigData('title');
    }
```